# MIPS signals in strace

Tags: mips, trace, strace

I am working with a linux minimalist kernel in a mips processor, both present in a embedded system. I am tracing the execution of a program, where I get this on strace:

`timer_gettime(0, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={0, 0}}) = 0
timer_settime(0, 0, {it_interval={0, 0}, it_value={7, 266000000}}, NULL) = 0`

(here is the deal breaker)

`rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x10000000, [RT_69 RT_70 RT_71 RT_72 RT_76 RT_77 RT_79 RT_82 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, {0x10000000, [RT_70 RT_71 RT_75 RT_77 RT_79 RT_80 RT_81 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, 16) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x10000000, [RT_69 RT_70 RT_71 RT_72 RT_76 RT_77 RT_79 RT_82 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, {0x10000000, [RT_70 RT_71 RT_75 RT_77 RT_79 RT_80 RT_81 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, 16) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x10000000, [RT_69 RT_70 RT_71 RT_72 RT_76 RT_77 RT_79 RT_82 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], 0}, {0x10000000, [RT_70 RT_71 RT_75 RT_77 RT_79 RT_80 RT_81 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_STACK|SA_INTERRUPT|0x2ac57d4}, 16) = 0
fork()                                  = 3489
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x10000000, [RT_69 RT_70 RT_71 RT_72 RT_76 RT_77 RT_79 RT_82 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, {0x10000000, [RT_70 RT_71 RT_75 RT_77 RT_79 RT_80 RT_81 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, 16) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x10000000, [RT_69 RT_70 RT_71 RT_72 RT_76 RT_77 RT_79 RT_82 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, {0x10000000, [RT_70 RT_71 RT_75 RT_77 RT_79 RT_80 RT_81 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, 16) = 0
wait4(3489, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 1}], 0, NULL) = 3489
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {0x10000000, [RT_69 RT_70 RT_71 RT_72 RT_76 RT_77 RT_79 RT_82 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, {0x10000000, [RT_70 RT_71 RT_75 RT_77 RT_79 RT_80 RT_81 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, 16) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x10000000, [RT_69 RT_70 RT_71 RT_72 RT_76 RT_77 RT_79 RT_82 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, {0x10000000, [RT_70 RT_71 RT_75 RT_77 RT_79 RT_80 RT_81 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_NOCLDSTOP}, 16) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {0x10000000, [RT_69 RT_70 RT_71 RT_72 RT_76 RT_77 RT_79 RT_82 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], SA_STACK|SA_INTERRUPT|0x2ac57d4}, {0x10000000, [RT_70 RT_71 RT_75 RT_77 RT_79 RT_80 RT_81 RT_83 RT_84 RT_86 RT_88 RT_90 RT_92 RT_94], 0}, 16) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_DFL, [], SA_STACK|SA_INTERRUPT|SA_SIGINFO|0x2eac360}, {SIG_DFL, [RT_67 RT_70 RT_73 RT_75 RT_77 RT_78 RT_82 RT_83 RT_84 RT_87 RT_88 RT_89 RT_90 RT_91 RT_92 RT_93 RT_94], 0}, 16) = 0
time([3380072])                         = 3380072`

The sigaction manual reads:

> The sigaction() system call is used to change the action taken by a
>          process on receipt of a specific signal.  (See signal(7) for an
>          overview of signals.)

I would like to know what is actually happening here and what are the RT_*X* elements.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have a question?   I don't see a question here.

Comment: Yes, I would like to know what actions are those signals triggering.